# Best approach to forward upload stream

Tags: node.js, rest, post, stream, restify

I'm working on REST server script written in NodeJS. This script lets user do POST request for uploading files. Since my server is not responsible to store files and it is taken care of by another remote server which is also REST server, I like to forward/redirect file upload stream to that remote server. What is the best approach to do that?

Should I buffer the stream and wait until I receive file in its entirety before streaming it to the remote server? Or

Should I just pipe the chunks to remote server as I receive them? I tried piping in my upload route with this statement -

```
req.pipe(request.post(connection).pipe(res)
```

but I received an error from the remote server - "Connection has been cancelled by the client". Or

Is it possible to redirect the incoming upload stream to that remote server so that my script wouldn't be a middleman?

Thanks

Comment: I found the culprit of that error. It's Postman plugin for Chrome that is not uploading file. So req.pipe is not getting any data and causes it to issue Connection cancelled error.